# State space transformation

Tags: linear-systems, state-space

I have some governing equations of the form:

$$\begin{align}
\ddot \theta(t) &= \frac{MgL + mgl}{J} \theta(t) + \frac B J \dot x(t) - \frac \alpha J V + \frac {mg}{J} d - \frac{c_1}{J} \dot \theta(t) \\
\ddot x &= \frac{\alpha}{R(M+m)} V - \frac{\beta/R + c_2}{M+m} \dot x(t)
\end{align} \tag 1$$

And I would like to transform them to the state space. I'd like them final equation to take the form of  $\dot z(t) = Az(t)+Bu(t)+T$, where $z(t) = (\theta, \dot \theta, \dot x)$ is the state vector. And I'd like for $U$ to contain $V$ and for $T$ to be a vector containing the disturbance torque $mgd/J$.

How would I go about this? I'm having trouble conceptualizing the internal relationships between the states. How would I write the governing equations in state space form?

And for the measurements, Id like to measure all three states.

Comment: It's not as painful as one might imagine, but I really wish that every poster uses $\LaTeX$ math markup instead of posting pictures of equations.  [There is even a Stack Exchange for it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sometimes if you're a newbie, someone will come along and do it for you -- once.

Comment: I believe you want $z(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \dot \theta & \theta & \dot x \end{bmatrix}^T$.  If so, where you want that to appear, _edit your question_ with `$z(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \dot \theta & \theta & \dot x \end{bmatrix}^T$`.

Comment: @TimWescott I have done that for a couple of newbies.  But this was a much bigger job and I didn't wanna research how to do single or double dot.

Comment: $\ddot \theta$ = `$\ddot \theta$`.

Comment: I didnt know how to do that but I will for next time I promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $z(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \dot \theta & \theta & \dot x \end{bmatrix}^T$.  Take it's derivative:
$$
\frac d {dt} z(t) = \begin{bmatrix}\dot \theta \\ \theta \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\ddot \theta \\ \dot \theta \\ \ddot x\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now add the $\frac{d}{dt} \theta$ term to your (1):
$$\begin{align}
\ddot \theta(t) &= \frac{MgL + mgl}{J} \theta(t) + \frac B J \dot x(t) - \frac \alpha J V + \frac {mg}{J} d - \frac{c_1}{J} \dot \theta(t) \\
\dot \theta &= \dot \theta \\
\ddot x &= \frac{\alpha}{R(M+m)} V - \frac{\beta/R + c_2}{M+m} \dot x(t)
\end{align}$$

You should be able to pick out $\mathbf A$ by inspection:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix}\dot \theta \\ \theta \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 
- \frac{c_1}{J} & \frac{MgL + mgl}{J} & \frac B J \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & - \frac{\beta/R + c_2}{M+m}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\dot \theta \\ \theta \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
 - \frac \alpha J V + \frac {mg}{J} d  \\
0 \\
\frac{\alpha}{R(M+m)} V 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I think you should see at this point how to separate out the rest.

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry about the format once again